# ¿ Cómo desactivar o hacer desaparecer todos los Gameobjects de una escena en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo una escena en `unity` y cuando la partida acabe, me gustaría que todos los `gameobjects` de la escena desaparecieran, bien desactivándolos mediante código o reduciendolos de tamaño para evitar que se vean.

El problema es que no puedo crear como `public Gameobject` y asignarlos a éste y decir que cuando termine desaparezcan, ya que tengo un `Generador de gameobjects` y son nuevos cada vez, por lo que antes de empezar la partida no existen. Por lo que busco algo así como una instrucción que diga que todos y cada uno de los gameobjects de la escena desaparezcan. ¿Existe?

ACTUALIZADO:

CODIGO DE LA PARTE DE GENERAR AUTOMATICAMENTE GameObjects

`public void Generar() {`

```
    if (EmpezarJuego.Activador_de_Generador == 1) {

        Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], transform.position, transform.rotation);
        InvokeRepeating ("Generar", 3, 180);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes meterlos en un List<GameObject> ... y cuando quieras destruir todos esos objetos solo recorre la lista.

Answer (score 0):

Si compartes el código de tu generador de gameobjects seguro que se puede hacer de una manera mucho más optima, pero si lo que buscas es exactamente lo que pedías en tu pregunta, quitar todo a las bravas, aquí te dejo el código con el que puedes hacer esto:

```
foreach (GameObject o in Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()) {
    Destroy(o);
}
```

Es un bucle que recorre todos los objetos de la clase GameObject de la escena y va destruyéndolos uno a uno.

Entiendo que los gameobjects que quieres quitar no pretendes volver a utilizarlos a posteriori, pero en caso que que simplemente solo quieras desactivarlos (cosa que no es recomendable si no vas a volver a utilizarlos ya que no se liberan de memoria como al eliminarlos con `Destroy()`) podrías utilizar el mismo bucle pero desactivándolos con la propiedad `SetActive(false)`:

```
foreach (GameObject o in Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()) {
    o.SetActive(false);
}
```

También quería comentar que lo que pides no es algo muy usual, ya que normalmente cuando en un juego termina la partida o acabas un nivel, en Unity se tiende a cargar una nueva escena (Ya sea una escena de gameover o volver a cargar la escena del juego). Al hacer esto todos los gameobjects de la escena anterior se destruirán liberándose en memoria, por lo que no será necesario eliminarlos manualmente a través de un script.

Comment: Heichi, estas? Si estás y contestas, puedo compartirte el código del generador de objetos a ver si podemos hacerlo óptimo como dices. Respecto a lo que pido yo que no es algo muy usual, ya, pero cuando acaba la partida, es muy común en mi juego que los quiera destruir, porque te va generando objetos cada X tiempo y en cuanto pierdes por culpa de 1 objeto , el resto se ven en la pantalla, y no puedo pasar a la siguiente porque necesito que veas tu puntuacion, está hecho así. Voy a probar lo que me has dicho a ver qué tal. Por favor, si lees esto, dimelo, un saludo.

Comment: Lo he ejecutado y me he dado cuenta que no puedo quitar gameobjects porque tambien me cargo la cámara por ejemplo.... puedo decir que todos excepto algunos gameobjects o similar?

Comment: o eliminar gameobjects que empiecen por "cube" o algo así.. sabes lo que me refiero?

Comment: Buenas @RfMvs , para que la página me notifique de tus respuestas y yo las lea a tiempo puedes probar a mencionarme con @ :P. Respecto a lo que me comentabas, no se si ya habrás dado con una solución dada la tardanza de la respuesta, pero básicamente podrías evitar que ciertos gameobjects no se destruyan poniendo un simple if dentro del bucle. Si el nombre del objeto es distinto del de tu cámara, entonces lo destruyes.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que detener lo que genera los **GameObjects**, creando un `bool` que al terminar la partida se convierta en `false`.

```
 if(Jugando == true){
  if (EmpezarJuego.Activador_de_Generador == 1) {

    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], transform.position, 
    transform.rotation);
    InvokeRepeating ("Generar", 3, 180);
}
}else{
/*Crear GameObject que contenga todos los otros componentes de la escena, y 
  que al momento de que jugando sea false, se desactivara. Tienes que poner 
  una etiqueta al GameObject principal que se genera, con la cual podras 
  detener 
  esos también.*/
 GameObject[] GO = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag");
 GO = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag");
 TodosComponentesEscena.SetActive(false);
}
```

Esto es una manera de hacerlo, espero que te sirva, si no te convence, utiliza la lógica de este código que te he creado y lo implementas de la manera que necesites.

Answer (score -1):

No se si es la mejor manera, pero yo crearía un gameObject(por ejemplo de nombre `general`) que englobe todos los demás gameObjects(es decir, que metas todos los gameObjects del escenario en `general`) y los que vayan apareciendo nuevos los haces hijos de dicho gameObject mediante programación.

Cuando necesites que desaparezcan simplemente haces esto:

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("general");

obj.setActive(false);
```

**EDIT:** En base a lo que has dicho en los comentarios, puedes probar con el siguiente código:

```
GameObject nuevoObjeto = Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.Length)], transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject; //Defines el objeto que quieras añadir al objeto padre
//Definimos el objeto en el que quieres instanciar el resto de objetos
GameObject objetoPadre;

//Obtenemos el transform del padre
Transform tsPadre = objetoPadre.GetComponent<Transform>();

//Objeto instanciado
nuevoObjeto.transform.SetParent(tsPadre);
```

Si tienes más dudas esta solucion la he obtenido de los foros de unity, [aqui](https://answers.unity.com/questions/572176/how-can-i-instantiate-a-gameobject-directly-into-a-1.html) y [aqui](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1289907/instantiating-a-new-gameobject-as-a-child-of-a-dif.html)

Comment: Alex, tal como he dicho, eso no sirve, ya que los objetos que quiero poner a false, NO existen antes de empezar la partida.

Comment: ¿Y si metieses el "obj.setActive(false)" para el generador de objects? No entiendo cómo funciona este objeto, pero a lo mejor te sirve. De todas formas, ¿cuál es la finalidad de crear este código? ¿El jugador seguirá jugando en el mapa que se ve? Si es así, no se otra solución que la que dice alex55132. Cuando generes los objetos hazlos hijos del Generador y así podrás ocultarlo fácilmente. **Explica cuál es tu finalidad y podremos ayudarte mejor.**

Comment: Claro, a eso me refería, edito la respuesta para que quede más claro @VickyVicent

Comment: Lo tuyo lo veo muy bien. Una solución muy factible, pero se lo decía a Rf Mvs, para que no se límite a las respuestas y que dé más información sobre la finalidad de lo que quiere hacer para que podamos ayudarle mejor. :)

Comment: Sí, a ver.... lo leeré y lo haré porque tiene buena pinta lo de heichi. Mi generador de objetos genera objetos, tal como dice el nombre, una vez acaba el juego, sale la puntuacion pero NO cambia de escena. Te sale los puntos obtenidos y los objetos que no has destrozado, se siguen viendo en la escena, cosa que no deseo pues el juego ha terminado. De ahí de eliminar todos los objetos. En la siguiente escena sí que los deseo tener, por lo que los desactivaré hasta que den click y os comentaré qué tal me ha salido. Gracias

Comment: Como puedo englobar todos dentro de uno mismo mediante codigo? Se generan cada X tiempo todo el rato. @alex55132

Comment: Me refiero... NO están creados cuando empieza la escena... se van creando conforme pasan la escena, ahi la dificultad. @alex55132

Comment: Prueba con lo que he puesto ahora en la respuesta y nos dices @RfMvs

Comment: antes de usar eso, mira lo que tengo yo, puede que si lo veas, me entendais mas, ACTUALIZADO ARRIBA

Comment: Mira a ver ahora @RfMvs

Comment: De acuerdo, al llegar le echo un ojo, muchas gracias, te comento en 2/3 días ,